# Create a Generic Base Adapter?

Tags: android, baseadapter, layout-inflater

I am interested in creating a generic BaseAdapter which will apply to any ListView having any list_item . And it will set the item_row for the list_view.

```
    public class GenericAdapter extends BaseAdapter
    {

    Context context;

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list;

    LayoutInflater inflater;

    public GenericAdapter (Context context, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list) 
        {
            this.context = context;

            this.list = list;

            inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

        @Override
        public int getCount()
        {
            return list.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position)
        {   
            return list.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position)
        {   
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            View view = convertView;

          if(view == null)
           {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_of_any_list, parent, false);

// i have to do something here like there may be a method which must be call 

           }

            /*HashMap<String, String> map = list.get(position);

            TextView textViewName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);

            TextView textViewDate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.date);

            //TextView textViewDesc = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.desc);

            textViewName.setText(map.get("name"));

            textViewDate.setText(map.get("date"));

            //textViewDesc.setText(map.get("description"));
    */      
            return view;
        }
```

I think i have to create an interface that's get and set the item_row for individual item. But i don't know it may be possible . Can someone tell me how i can achieve it.

My idea is to create an interface and GenericAdapter implements that interface. In that interface there is a method to get and set the item_row. Any class which extends GenericAdapter must implement that method. it will  help us  make a generic adapter.

When we extend that adapter we don't need to write all code like getCount, getItem,getItemId, we just have to override a function which is to inflateLayout. which must be inside getView

Thanks in Advance

Comment: If you do not want to write custom adapters, consider using an existing library, like https://github.com/ribot/easy-adapter or http://amigold.github.io/FunDapter/

Comment: See this [Generic adapter](https://github.com/sajadshokri/Core-Adapter)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Answering my own Question after two years.**

In order to make **Generic Adapter** you need `abstract` methods in `parent class` which should be implemented by `child`. So `GenericAdapter` must be `Abstract` and create `abstract` methods for data you want to change.

I have different types of **ArrayList** to show in Adapter only it's `model class` is different. So I decided to write a `genericAdapter`. This is for `recyclerview` if someOne `interested` for listview. Let me know.

**GenericAdapter**

```
public abstract class GenericAdapter<T> extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<T> items;

    public abstract RecyclerView.ViewHolder setViewHolder(ViewGroup parent);

    public abstract void onBindData(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, T val);

    public GenericAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<T> items){
        this.context = context;
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder = setViewHolder(parent);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        onBindData(holder,items.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    public void addItems( ArrayList<T> savedCardItemz){
        items = savedCardItemz;
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public T getItem(int position){
        return items.get(position);
    }
}
```

And I use it like

```
     adapter = new GenericAdapter<DataModel>(context,modelList) {
        @Override
        public RecyclerView.ViewHolder setViewHolder(ViewGroup parent) {
            final View view =            LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_view_holder, parent, false);
            ItemViewHolder viewHolder = new ItemViewHolder(context, view);
            return viewHolder;
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindData(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder1, DataModel val) {
                DataModel userModel = val;

                ItemViewHolder holder = (ItemViewHolder)holder1;
                holder.name.setText(userModel.getName());
                holder.fatherName.setText(userModel.getFatherName());
        }
    };
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

**[RecyclerView with Search sort functionality](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/173504/147058)**

Comment: @Nepster your code **doesn't work for multiple types adapter**. Actually, I can see it doesn't enough 'generic'.  Your abstract methods are nothing than wrapper methods from RecycleView Adapter (`setViewHolder` is a wrapper of `onCreateViewHolder`, `onBindData` is wrapping for `onBindViewHolder`) This pattern will work for Adapter ListView instead of Recycle Adapter. Just my though

Comment: @R4j Give suggestion to improve it. And how can I implement generic filter on the basis of type

Comment: May be it helps https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/173504/generic-adapter-with-search-and-sort-functionality

Answer (score 1):

I have created a generic adapter, the aar and the sources are at [this url](https://github.com/MaximeJallu/RecyclerAdapter-Java):

it's easy usage:

```
RecyclerAdapter<Customer> mAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(customerList, CustomerViewHolder.class);
```

see Url link more details

Answer (score 1):

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;

import java.util.List;

public abstract class GenericAdapter<T> extends BaseAdapter {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    Context context;
    private List<T> tList;



public GenericAdapter(Context context, List<T> tList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.tList = tList;
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        if (tList == null)
            return 0;
        return tList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return tList.get(position);
    }


    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    public abstract View getMyView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent,T t);

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return getMyView(position, convertView, parent,tList.get(position));
    }

}
```

and you can use it like

```
spnDistrict.setAdapter(new GenericAdapter<Institutions>(getContext(), institutionsList) {
            @Override
            public View getMyView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent, Institutions institutions) {
                TextView textView = (TextView) convertView;
                if (textView == null) {
                    textView = (TextView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, null);
                    textView.setTextColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
                }
                textView.setText(institutions.getName());
                return textView;
            }
        });
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, it is better to explain the essential parts of the answer and possibly what was the problem with OPs code.

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

import com.accel.cloudRDB.model.OpenTask;

public class Open_task_fragment extends Fragment {
    View view;
    ListView mListView;
    Open_task_adapter open_task_adapter;
    Context mContext;
    ArrayList<OpenTask> items;
    Button main_menu;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

        mContext=getActivity();
        view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.open_task_layout, container,false);
        items=new ArrayList<OpenTask>();
        initXML();
        OpenTask open=new OpenTask();
         open.setDate("10/10/2014");
         open.setTime("12:00 pm");
         open.setAddress("chennai Dlf,Accel@123");
         open.setStatus("Deliver ABC");
         OpenTask open1=new OpenTask();
         open1.setDate("10/10/2014");
         open1.setTime("12:00 pm");
         open1.setAddress("chennai Dlf,Accel@123");
         open1.setStatus("Deliver ABC2");
         items.add(open);
         items.add(open1);
         open_task_adapter=new Open_task_adapter(mContext,items);
//      open_task_adapter=new Open_task_adapter(mContext,items);
        mListView.setAdapter(open_task_adapter);
        mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1, int position,
                    long arg3) {

                    Intent intent=new Intent(mContext,Task_detail_activity.class);
                    ((Activity)mContext).startActivity(intent);
            }

        });
        return view;
    }
    public void initXML()
    {
        mListView=(ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        main_menu=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.main_menu);
    }

}
```

model:

```
public class OpenTask {

    String Date,Time,Address,Status;

    public String getDate() {
        return Date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        Date = date;
    }

    public String getTime() {
        return Time;
    }

    public void setTime(String time) {
        Time = time;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return Address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        Address = address;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return Status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        Status = status;
    }

}
```

adapter:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class Open_task_adapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context context;

    ArrayList<OpenTask> list;

    public Open_task_adapter(Context context,ArrayList<OpenTask> list) {

        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        OpenTaskHolder hodler;
        LayoutInflater inflater;
        OpenTask open=list.get(position);
        if (convertView == null) 
        {
            inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.open_task_list_item_layout, null);
            hodler = new OpenTaskHolder();
            hodler.date = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.Date);
            hodler.time = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.Time);
            hodler.address = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.Address);
            hodler.status = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.Status);

            convertView.setTag(hodler);
        } else {
            hodler = (OpenTaskHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }

        hodler.date.setText(open.getDate());
        hodler.time.setText(open.getTime());
        hodler.address.setText(open.getAddress());
        hodler.status.setText(open.getStatus());

        return convertView;
    }

    class OpenTaskHolder {
        TextView date,time,address,status;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain how this answers the question.

Comment: @CommonsWare we can acheive in this way

Comment: lazy cowards,down voter give comment what did i wrong from here?