# Android RecyclerView with 5 different views

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerview for my search and I want to add all of my items to it.I have **5 models** of data I write.

This code so far but its only show first 2 items only 2 please can you tell me what's wrong?

**my Adapter for recyclerView code:**

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (models.getEvents().size() >= position && position >= 0){
        code = 0;
    }else if (position > models.getEvents().size() && position <= (models.getEvents().size()+models.getNews().size())){
        code = 1;
    }else if (position > (models.getNews().size()+models.getEvents().size()) && position <=
            (models.getEvents().size()+models.getNews().size()+models.getMemes().size())){
        code =2;
    }else if (position >(models.getEvents().size()+models.getNews().size()+models.getMemes().size())
    && position <= (models.getNews().size()+models.getEvents().size()+models.getMemes().size()+models.getExSites().size())){
        code = 3;
    }else if (position >(models.getNews().size()+models.getEvents().size()+models.getMemes().size()+models.getExSites().size()) &&position <=
            (models.getNews().size()+models.getEvents().size()+models.getMemes().size()+models.getExSites().size()+models.getTwitch().size())){
        code =4;
    }
    return code;
}
@Override
public SearchViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    switch (viewType){
        case 0:
            view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.events_layout,parent,false);
            return new SearchViewHolder(view);
        case 1:
            view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.news_layout,parent,false);
            return new SearchViewHolder(view);
        case 2:
            view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.last_world_memes_list_item,parent,false);
            return new SearchViewHolder(view);
        case 3:
            view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.last_url_view,parent,false);
            return new SearchViewHolder(view);
        case 5:
            view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.twitch,parent,false);
            return new SearchViewHolder(view);
    }

    return new SearchViewHolder(view);
}
```

**and here my bind View**

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(SearchViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    switch (holder.getItemViewType()){
        case 0:
            Events event = models.getEvents().get(position);
        do works
            return;
        case 1:
            final LastWorldMemes mNews = models.getNews().get(position-(models.getEvents().size()));

        do works
            return;
        case 2:
            LastWorldMemes memes = models.getMemes().get(position-(models.getEvents().size()+models.getNews().size()));

        do works
            return;
        case 3:
        do works
            return;
        case 4:

    }
}
```

**the problem is get itemCount on recyclerview this is my code and here is the error**

```
int size =( models.getEvents().size()+models.getNews().size()+models.getTwitch().size()
        +models.getExSites().size()+models.getMemes().size());
  @Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return size;
}
```

and this is the error

```
02-19 18:27:38.216 14902-14902/app.mma.introsliderproject E/UncaughtException: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 8, Size: 8
                                                                               at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:411)
                                                                               at app.mma.PokerInfo.search.SearchAdapter.onBindViewHolder(SearchAdapter.java:109)
                                                                               at app.mma.PokerInfo.search.SearchAdapter.onBindViewHolder(SearchAdapter.java:35)
```

Comment: Please check this maybe this can help you https://gist.github.com/hablodemi/bfc8bf3b41f70838beaa5d9089b6bda9 and how are you making the calculation for getCount?

Comment: First of all in your onCreateViewHolder exit case 5 and not case 4 that in getItemViewType is present

Comment: case 5: should be case 4:

Comment: dear @an_droid_dev and Penmonic i change it but its same nothing change its only show first 2 items (Events)

Comment: @Pnemonic its same

Comment: @DinorahTovar thanks a lot but its so simple my lists is not same size

Comment: @Sadegh what items have you inside your array? Can you post also xml from adapter item and activity / fragment layout? If you scroll it reach limit (shadow top / bottom)?

Comment: i find the problem but now i cant solve it can you help me please? i will edit my post @an_droid_dev

Comment: @Sadegh of course

Comment: @an_droid_dev thanks a lot post edited

Comment: @Sadegh the sum of all items is inside getItemCount()?

Comment: yea @an_droid_dev

Comment: @Sadegh i understand the problem. I write an answer

Comment: @an_droid_dev thanks a lot you made my day :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that: you don't have an array as data, but conceptually an matrix. So what happen, total count is the sum of all childs of all your arrays. For example, you have 3 events and 2 news, when adapter reach 4 position it tell you inside onBind position 3, so you go to get inside news array the news with position 3, but you have only 2 news.

**Solution**

imho, you should put all items (news , events, etc) inside one array (maybe if array is generic ArrayList< T >) for example inside adapter constructor or create a method that update your adapter.

i hope to was cleary if it's not post a comment

**Edit**

For understand what type of item are you get from array you can use

```
if(array.get(position) instanceof NewsItem{
   // here we have a news item
}
```

Comment: what a great Solution but i want to know you say me put all off my items in one array with tags and in getViewtype() i should write if tag.equals("event"){viewtype =0 }???

Comment: @Sadegh you can use instanceof to check type of item. I edit my answer

Comment: i know what you say but i dont know how get instance i will search thanks a lot and if you can tell me that be wonderful

Comment: i really confused how can put all of my items in one array?i should create a model for my all items?

Comment: You should create inside your adapter an array generic (i don't now if you know Generics in Java, if not use Object) like this ArrayList<Object> allItems = new ArrayList()<> and iterate all of your models and put its inside array

Comment: this is an example of Adapter with generics https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24994661/custom-android-adapter-with-generic-class

Comment: i get it thanks a lot for your time i wish i could do something for you <3

Answer (score 0):

I think there is too much confusion in `getItemViewType`

try simplify:

```
final int eventsPositions = models.getEvents().size();
final int newsPositions = eventsPositions + models.getNews().size();
final int memesPositions = newsPositions + models.getMemes().size();
final int exSitesPositions = memesPositions + models.getExSites().size();

if (position < eventsSize) {
    code = 0;
} else if (position < newsPositions) {
   code = 1;
} else if (position < memesPositions) {
    code = 2;
} else if (position < exSitesPositions) {
    code = 3;
} else {
    code = 4;
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for answer but with this method its too hard to get the size and adapter to get models is harder too but with acepted answer method you can just do Events event = models.get(postion); its so simple but on your way you should do Events event = models.get(postion+news.size);