# Convert custom adapter to use generics in Java

Tags: java, generics

I have a Adapter in my Android app and I want to make it Generic.

Basiclly the Adapter looks like that:

```
public class myAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

DataTypaA myFragment;
DataTypeB data;
DataTypeC items;

public myAdapter(FragmentManager fm, DataTypaA fragment) {
        data = new SparseArray<DataTypeB>();
        myFragment = fragment;
        items = myFragment.getData();
    }

    public DataTypeB getItem(int position) {
        return data.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.getList().size();
    }


public void setData () {

items = myFragment.getItems ()  //getItems return DataTypeC
data.setTheData (items) 
}
}
```

I changed it to generic

```
public class myAdapter <A,B,C> extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

A myFragment;
B data;
C items;

public myAdapter(FragmentManager fm, A fragment) {
        data = new SparseArray<B>();
        myFragment = fragment;
        items =  (C) myFragment.getData();
    }

    public B getItem(int position) {
        return data.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.getList().size();
    }


public void setData () {

items = myFragment.getItems ()  //getItems return DataTypeC
data.setTheData (items) 
}
}
```

but I'm getting different errors, when methods should get `DataTypeC` parameter and I passing it parameter type `C` ( `data.setTheData (items)`  ) that is actually type `DataTypeC` the compiler suggest to cast `C` to type `DataTypeC`. and in `getCount()` I have also error suggesting to convert `items` to `DataTypeC`.

for example when I try to override getItem I getting mistakes, but when I create the same method with other name it compiles.

```
//Error - "The return type is incompatible with FragmentStatePagerAdapter.getItem(int)"
@Override
    public B getItem(int position) {
        return (B) data.get(position);
    }

//compiles
    public B getItemTest(int position) {
        return data.get(position);
    }
```

Any ideas how to fix it so it will be 100% generic?

**ADDED**:     After your answer I changes it to support return of generic type :

```
   public class TypeA <T> {
    private T mData;

        public T getData() { return mData;; }
    }



    public class myAdapter <A,B,C> extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

        A myFragment;
        B data;
        C items;

        public myAdapter(FragmentManager fm, A fragment) {
                data = new SparseArray<B>();
                myFragment = fragment;
                items = myFragment.getData(); //Error - The method getData() is undefined for the type T
            }

}
```

I'm getting compile error...
when I run it of course  `<T>` and `<C>` are the same type.

Comment: Why do you want to make it generic? Can you provide a use-case? It is not clear what you're trying to achieve (or at least to me ;)): `data` is of type `DataTypeB` or `SparseArray<DataTypeB>`?

Comment: @Matthieu `data` is type `B`, it was a mistake, thank you...This adapter has some logic that I want to give the use of it to other classes , and they just would need to set the type `<A,B,C>` and not copying code and creating new adapters.

Comment: Alex, you should really make sure that your code makes sense before you post it. Your non-generic code doesn't compile at all, so its hard to make any sensible recommendations.

Comment: also see this http://stackoverflow.com/a/38350061/3496570

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem is that your non-generic code doesn't compile. You have a field `DataTypeB data;` which you then assign a `SparseArray<DataTypeB>` to. Also, `setData` doesn't compile at all.

Ignoring this... you have declared type parameters `A, B, C` and changed your instance field types, but you still try and assign `DataTypaA` to `A myFragment` in your constructor, and a `SparseArray<DataTypeB>` to `B data`. When you migrate code to generics you need to approach it like you would refactoring - one step at a time.

For instance, by diving in as you have now take a look at `items = (C)myFragment.getData()`. As `fragment` is still of type `DataTypaA` then presumably its `getData()` method doesn't return a generic type. Something is going to have to change.

You have a lot of work to do, so to repeat myself - treat this as a refactoring exercise and go step by step.

1. Get your non-generic type to compile.
2. Change `myFragment` to be a `A myFragment` and declare a type parameter `<A extends DataTypaA`. See what needs to be done to get this to compile before moving on.
3. Now look at moving `data` to be `SparseArray<B> data`. Presumably this needs to a `SparseArray<T>` where `T` is a `DataTypeB`, or subtype thereof. That means you are going to need a wildcard-based bound on `B`. Something like `B extends SparseArray<? extends DataTypeB>`
4. Now look at `items`. You know that it is returned from your new generic type variable `A extends DataTypeA`, so `DataTypeA` needs to be generic and have a generic type variable returned from `getData`. Let's say it is declared as `DataTypeA<T extends DataTypeC>` with `public T getData() { ... }`.

So now your type parameter sections change to:

```
class DataTypaA<T extends DataTypeC>
...
class myAdapter <A extends DataTypaA<C>, 
                 B extends SparseArray<? extends DataTypeB>, 
                 C extends DataTypeC> 
    extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter { 
    A myFragment;
    SparseArray<B> data;
    C items;
...
```

It's hard to go too far with this given the code you have posted - not all the classes and information is there, but this is the process you will have to follow.

For instance: you may not need to restrict `C` to `DataTypeC`. This then changes the type parameter sections on `myAdapter` and `DataTypeA`. My assumption about `SparseArray<B>` may also be incorrect - but your code doesn't compile at the moment so I can't tell. A final implementation *may* go something like:

```
class myAdapter <A extends DataTypaA<C>, 
                 B extends SparseArray<? extends DataTypeB, 
                                       ? extends DataTypeC>, 
                 C extends DataTypeC> 
    extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    A myFragment;
    SparseArray<B, C> data;
    C items;

    public myAdapter(FragmentManager fm, A fragment) {
        data = new SparseArray<B, C>();
        myFragment = fragment;
        items =  myFragment.getData();
    }

    public B getItem(int position) {
        return data.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.getList().size();
    }   

    public void setData () {
        items = myFragment.getItems ();  //getItems return DataTypeC
        data.setTheData(items);
    }
}
```

For this I used the fake classes:

```
class DataTypaA<T extends DataTypeC> {
    public T getData() { return null; }
    public T getItems() { return null; }
}
class SparseArray<T, S> {
    public T get(int foo) { return null; }
    public void setTheData(S items){}
}
class DataTypeB {
}
class DataTypeC {
    // do NOT use the raw type List - just done to get your code to compile
    public List getList() { return null; }
}
abstract class FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    public abstract int getCount();
}
class FragmentManager {
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I fixed the syntax errors with the types, It's actually don't compile, and I write it for the big idea. I dont use  `<T extends...> `because it should work with types that not have something similar. My problems is when I initialise an parameter that should return the `<T>` type like in `public B getItem(int position) {
        return data.get(position);` I get error while it override, If I change the name then it acceptable. also I have problem with `getCount()` - I extends it from Android class so I cant rewrite it with abstract as you suggested
    }

Comment: @AlexOpent. Using `abstract` isn't necessary for `getCount` - I just had to fake those classes rather than load in the Android libraries. `extends` is optional - it depends on how you need to use the type parameters.

Comment: @AlexOpent. For your other question about `public B getItem(int position) { return data.get(position);` you should ask a new question about overriding non-generic supertype methods.

Comment: O.K I'll ask a new question about it is it something different? so basically what you saying is if I want that the next line will work : `items = myFragment.getItems ();`  (where `items` is type `C`) I need to rewrite the getItems() so besides returning type C what it's doing today, It should also return generic type for that line?

Comment: @AlexOpent. That's one option, there are others. It's definitely a question in itself.

Comment: I tried what you sujested,  to set return type of method to generic (not  overriding non-generic supertype methods) but private of a class, but I getting error, see ADDED in my quesiotn

Comment: @AlexOpent. I'm sorry - SO is strictly for one question per posted question. You will get better help if you post a new question with your new problem. There are lots of other people on SO who can help if you post a new question.

Answer (score 0):

When "genericizing" classes, you should replace all instances of genericized types by their generic: `DataTypaA` becomes `A`, etc.

You also need to make sure return types from methods you call on other objects (like `fragment.getData()`) are compatible with the generic. For that you can indicate the generic type extends a known class:

```
public class MyAdapter<A extends MyData,B extends MyData,...>
```

The [Java Tutorial on generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/) is good for more information.